# unable to read from file when user provides filename (x86 assembly program using nasm)

Tags: linux, file, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm having a problem trying to open a file  and read from it. The user is prompted for the file name.

The program compiles without error but doesn't show anything. When I hardcode the filename in the `.data` section it runs fine, but when I get the filename from the user it fails to read the file. Where am I doing wrong? I can't find any error.

Output using hardcoded name: `welcome`

Output when user enters the name: `���`

Here is my code:

```
section .data
    promptUsr db 'enter a file name:',0xA,0xD
    lenPrompt equ $-promptUsr
    info db 1
    ;file_name db 'data.txt' (NOTE:harcoded name works when used)
section .bss
    fd_in resb 1
    buffer resb 7
    file_name resb 20  
section .text
    global _start
_start:

;prompt user to enter a file name
        mov eax,4   ;sys_write
        mov ebx,1   ;stdout
        mov ecx,promptUsr
        mov edx,lenPrompt
    int 0x80

;read filename  (NOTE:when user enters the same name 'data.txt',this is the output:���)
        mov eax,3   
        mov ebx,2   
        mov ecx,file_name   ;(NOTE:tried using 'dword[file_name]',doesnt work)
        mov edx,20
    int 0x80

;open file 
    mov eax,5
    mov ebx,file_name   ;(NOTE:also tried using 'dword[file_name]',doesnt work too)
    mov ecx,2           ;read n write
    mov edx,7777h   ;all file permissions
   int 0x80 
    mov [fd_in],eax 

;read 7 bytes of the file
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,[fd_in]
    mov ecx,buffer  
    mov edx,7       
    int 0x80    

;close the file
    mov eax,6
   int 0x80
;print out what was read
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,buffer
    mov edx,7
   int 0x80
;end program
    mov eax,1
   int 0x80
```

Comment: would also love to know how to check first if the file exists before opening it.thanx anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what Michael says... 1) `fd_in` is too small - make it `resd 1`. 2) `sys_read` doesn't return a zero-terminated string, and `sys_open` wants one.

```
mov byte [ecx + eax - 1], 0
```

after the `sys_read` of the filename should zero-terminate it.

Comment: thanx frank.just tried that but cant get the read right

where exactly should i insert the mov byte [ecx + eax - 1], 0 c0de?
inserting it just after 'mov ebx,0' didnt work.inserting after mov ecx,file_name doesnt work either...the code runs but nothing is displyed.

note the following wierd  symbols output

when i change resd 1 to resb1,this is output :���
when i make it resb 2,output is:��
resb 3 output is:�
returning it to resd 1,nothing displayed.

whats the issue here?

then how come the program runs fine when i hardcode the filename yet i reserved only one byte for the file descriptor?

Comment: Put that zero-termination line after the `int 80h`. `ecx` is (still) your buffer, and `eax` is the length read, including the terminating linefeed. You're correct that there's a hidden character there. We want to overwrite it with another hidden character - the zero that `sys_open` expects to be there.

Comment: ooh my!!finally! thanks alot..it now works as expected.youre a saviour.this code has been giving me a headache since morning.interesting how the terminating 0 is added after int 80h.i thought after int 80h the filename has already been saved.
now all that remains is a way to check if the file exists such that if it doesnt a message is displayed and program exits.
i am new to assembly n have no idea how syscall 33 or 18 r used.

how about using:
cmp eax,0
jbe end

just before mov [fd_in],eax?

Comment: Try `man 2 access` - it's in C, but you can figure it out. Or you can check the value in `eax` after the `sys_open` as you suggest, and if it didn't succeed, see why not. (errno.h)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to read from `STDERR`:

```
mov eax,3   
mov ebx,2   
mov ecx,file_name   ;(NOTE:tried using 'dword[file_name]',doesnt work)
mov edx,20
```

That `mov ebx,2` ought to be `mov ebx,0` if you want to read from `STDIN`.

---

> would also love to know how to check first if the file exists before opening it

If you use `sys_open` without the `O_CREAT` flag set, it should fail and return -1 if the file doesn't already exist. You could also use [`access`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) ([syscall 33](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html)) or [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) ([syscall 18](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html)) if you want to.

Comment: thanx michael for quick reply....
i have changed the mov ebx,2 to mov ebx,0 but still not able to read the file..the file can only be read if i declare the name within the code.i think maybe using std_in inserts some hidden character(a terminating character) or something at the end of the file name?maybe this invisible character should be stripped off before opening the file using that name?

so if this were the case ,do you have an idea how to delete the last character from a string?

when i add code to print out what the user entered,it displays it just fine i.e.'data.txt'
any ideas?